# Why inline elements have additional margin at the bottom?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following testing page. Basically it draws a border around the element under the mouse and displays a tooltip at the bottom-left of the element. For block elements, there is no issue.

[image]

But for inline elements, there is always a gap between the highlighted element and the tooltip.

[image]

I tried to add 0 margin for these inline elements but of no avail. Could anyone help to point in the right direction?
To make debugging easier, I created this codepen post: https://codepen.io/ogrishman/pen/gObMNWa

```js
var tip = jQuery("<div id='tip' style='display:none;'></div>");
tip.appendTo("body");
jQuery("*").on("mouseover", function (event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    var thisj = jQuery(this);
    var thisj_pos = thisj.offset();

    thisj.css("border", "2px solid red");
    tip.text(thisj.prop("tagName"));

    $("#tip").css({
        "top": thisj_pos.top + thisj.outerHeight(),
        "left": thisj_pos.left,
        display: "block"
    });
}).on("mouseout", function (event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    jQuery(this).css("border", "")
});
```

```css
#b {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: #0fa3e0;
  border: 10px solid grey;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 100px;
}

#s {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #ff0000;
  border: 10px solid gold;
  position: absolute;
}

#tip {
  border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
  border: 2px solid #000000;
  background-color: #fdf0ca;
  position: absolute;
  color: #000000;
  padding: 3px;
}
```

```html
<div id="b"></div>
<div id="s"></div>
<div style="position: absolute; top: 300px;">
    <a href="#">Test anchor 1</a>
    <a href="#">Test anchor 2</a>
    <a href="#">Test anchor 3</a>
    <a href="#">Test anchor 4</a>
    <a href="#">Test anchor 5</a>
    <br />
    <span>Test span 1</span>
    <span>Test span 2</span>
    <span>Test span 3</span>
    <span>Test span 4</span>
    <span>Test span 5</span>
    <br />
    <p>test paragraph 1</p>
    <p>test paragraph 2</p>
    <p>test paragraph 3</p>
    <p>test paragraph 4</p>
    <p>test paragraph 5</p>
</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because you are applying the border after getting the offset of the element. Since the border-top/bottom doesn't affect the layout when it comes to inline element it will not push the element down and you will get a gap exactly equal to the border-top thickness.

Add the border before to get the correct offset and fix the issue:

```js
var tip = jQuery("<div id='tip' style='display:none;'></div>");
tip.appendTo("body");
jQuery("a").on("mouseover", function(event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
  var thisj = jQuery(this);
   thisj.css("border", "5px solid red");
  var thisj_pos = thisj.offset();

  tip.text(thisj.prop("tagName"));

  $("#tip").css({
    "top": thisj_pos.top + thisj.outerHeight(),
    "left": thisj_pos.left,
    display: "block"
  });
}).on("mouseout", function(event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
   jQuery(this).css("border", "")
});
```

```css
#tip {
  border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
  border: 2px solid #000000;
  background-color: #fdf0ca;
  position: absolute;
  color: #000000;
  padding: 3px;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" >Test j anchor 1</a>
<a href="#" >Test anchor 2</a>
<a href="#" >Test anchor 3</a>
<a href="#" >Test anchor 4</a>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Here is a code to better illustrate the issue:

```js
var tip = jQuery("<div id='tip' style='display:none;'></div>");
tip.appendTo("body");
jQuery("a.before").on("mouseover", function(event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
  var thisj = jQuery(this);
   thisj.css("border", "10px solid red");
  var thisj_pos = thisj.offset();

  tip.text(thisj.prop("tagName"));
  console.log(thisj_pos.top)
  $("#tip").css({
    "top": thisj_pos.top + thisj.outerHeight(),
    "left": thisj_pos.left,
    display: "block"
  });
}).on("mouseout", function(event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
   jQuery(this).css("border", "")
});
jQuery("a.after").on("mouseover", function(event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
  var thisj = jQuery(this);
  var thisj_pos = thisj.offset();
   thisj.css("border", "10px solid red");

  tip.text(thisj.prop("tagName"));
 console.log(thisj_pos.top)
  $("#tip").css({
    "top": thisj_pos.top + thisj.outerHeight(),
    "left": thisj_pos.left,
    display: "block"
  });
}).on("mouseout", function(event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
   jQuery(this).css("border", "")
});
```

```css
#tip {
  border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
  border: 2px solid #000000;
  background-color: #fdf0ca;
  position: absolute;
  color: #000000;
  padding: 3px;
}

a {
 margin: 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="before">inline element</a>
<a href="#" class="after">inline element</a>
<a href="#" class="before" style="display:inline-block;">inline block element</a>
<a href="#" class="after" style="display:inline-block;">inline block element</a>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

You can clearly see that inline elements will not move down when you add the border unline inline-block (or block) element. With inline-block adding the border before or after doesn't make a difference since the element will always have the same top value but inline element will have different top value after adding a border:

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer!

Answer (score 1):

In order to add margins to inline elements, you have to add `display: inline-block`. As I remember, `display: inline` doesn't take into consideration the `box-model`.
Basically, the box model let us manage margins/paddings of the elements.

More on box-model here: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_boxmodel.asp

Comment: hmm you are correct. However I thought the OP's question was "Why is there a gap?" not "How do I change the margin of an inline element?". This doesn't really answer the actual question.

Comment: *As I remember, display: inline doesn't take into consideration the box-model* --> this is false and getting 3 upvotes for such answer is suspicious

Comment: What's more suspicious is that I flagged this as not an answer and it has been successfully disputed.

Comment: @TemaniAfif I guess SO is giving out participation trophies now. You didn't even come close to the right answer and nobody should be reading your dis-information but we'll give you points for trying.

Answer (score 1):

try this one:

```js
const boundingClientRect = this.getBoundingClientRect()

$("#tip").css({
    top: boundingClientRect.top + boundingClientRect.height + window.scrollY,
    left: boundingClientRect.left + window.scrollX,
    display: "block"
});
```